# Check contents of a map without increasing the size

Tags: c++, dictionary

How do I check the value of map at a given `Pair` without appending another node? Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

struct Pair{
    int key1,key2;
    Pair(int k1,int k2):key1(k1),key2(k2) {}
    friend bool operator<(const Pair &a, const Pair &b){
        return a.key1 < b.key1;
    }
};
map<Pair,int> m;
int check(Pair p){
    return m[p];
}

void increment(Pair p){
    m[p]++;
}

int main(){

    int x = check(Pair(1,2)); // Should not add new node
    cout<<x<<endl;
    increment(Pair(2,3)); 
    x = check(Pair(2,3));
    cout<<x<<endl;

    char ch;cin>>ch;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why would the `key` in a _key value_ pair be a pair itself?

Comment: In my actual program the `key` is `SpaceTime`. You know, space and time.

Comment: Btw why you define `struct Pair` instead of using `std::pair` or `std::tuple`?

Comment: Its a simplified version of my code. The actual code is more complicated than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [std::map::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)

```
int check(Pair p)
{
    auto found = m.find(p);
    if(found != m.end())
        return found->second;
    return 0; // ?? error not found
}
```

Of course what to do if the item is not found?

You could return a `bool`:

```
bool check(Pair p, int& i)
{
    auto found = m.find(p);
    if(found == m.end())
        return false; // not found
    i = found->second; // set the output parameter
    return true; // success
}
```

You can use that like this:

```
int main()
{
    int x;

    if(check(Pair(1,2), x))
        cout << x << endl; // only output if x was found

    increment(Pair(2,3)); 

    if(check(Pair(2,3), x))
        cout << x << endl; // only output if x was found

}
```

**NOTE:** The output parameter `int& i` is *pass by reference* so it can be changed from within the function. This is how we get the value that we find in the `std::map`.